# caught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having this error in my next js app when I start the app, it was throwing that error, I'm using react-redux for my state management with next version 13 with the appDir,when i remove the Provider coming from react redux the app works fine but when i add it back it throws that error, I'm actually not using JSON.parse in my code, I only wrapped the children with the ApolloProvider and the Provider as seen below

This is the full error: **caught SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
at JSON.parse ()
at parseModel (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:33:15)**

**This is my layout.tsx**

```
"use client"
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";
import SiteHeader from "./(client-components)/(Header)/SiteHeader";
import ClientCommons from "./ClientCommons";
import "./globals.css";
import "@/fonts/line-awesome-1.3.0/css/line-awesome.css";
import "@/styles/index.scss";
import "rc-slider/assets/index.css";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import FooterNav from "@/components/FooterNav";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../lib/store";
import client from "../lib/graphql";
const poppins = Poppins({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  display: "optional",
  weight: ["100", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800"],
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  params,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: any;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={poppins.className}>
      <body className="bg-white text-base dark:bg-neutral-900 text-neutral-900 dark:text-neutral-200">
       <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <ClientCommons />
            <SiteHeader />
            {children}
            <FooterNav />
            <Footer />
           </Provider>
        </ApolloProvider> 
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**This is my propertySlice.js**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { fetchProperties, fetchProperty } from "./propertiesApi";

const initialState = {
  
  data: [],
  propertyData: null,
  loading: true,
  error: null,
  searchQuery: {
    location: "",
    priceMin: null,
    priceMax: null,
    propertyTypes: [],
  },
  property: {},
  selectedListingId: null,
};

const propertiesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "properties",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setSelectedListing(state, action) {
      state.selectedListingId = action.payload;
    },
    setProperties(state, action) {
      state.items = action.payload;
    },
    setSearchQuery(state, action) {
      state.searchQuery = action.payload;
    },
    setProperty(state, action) {
      state.property = action.payload;
    },
    setLoading(state, action) {
      state.loading = action.payload;
    },
    setError(state, action) {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchProperties.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProperties.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.data = payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProperties.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProperty.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
        state.error = null;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProperty.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = null;
        state.property = payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchProperty.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = payload;
      });
  },
});

export const {
  setProperty,
  setLoading,
  setError,
  setProperties,
  setSearchQuery,
  setSelectedListing,
} = propertiesSlice.actions;

export default propertiesSlice.reducer;
```

**This is my propertiesApi.ts**

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { store } from "@/lib/store";
import client from "../../lib/graphql";
import { GET_AllProperties, Get_Property } from "../../graphql/queries";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export const fetchProperties = createAsyncThunk(
  "properties/fetchProperties",
  async () => {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: GET_AllProperties,
    });
    return data.allProperties;
  }
);

export const fetchProperty = createAsyncThunk(
  "property/fetchProperty",
  async (id) => {
    const variables = { id };
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: Get_Property,
      variables,
    });
    return data.property;
  }
);

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

**This is the store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import propertiesSlice from '../features/properties/propertiesSlice'
import userSlice from '../features/user/userSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
     properties: propertiesSlice,
     user: userSlice,
  },
});
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "chisfis-nextjs",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.12",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.16",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^5.0.1",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.15.0",
    "@netlify/plugin-nextjs": "^4.33.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^2.1.7",
    "@types/node": "18.14.2",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.10.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "client-only": "^0.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.2.3",
    "framer-motion": "^10.0.1",
    "geocoding": "^1.0.0",
    "google-map-react": "^2.2.0",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.13.0",
    "next": "^13.2.4-canary.9",
    "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
    "rc-slider": "^10.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0", 
    "react-datepicker": "^4.10.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hooks-global-state": "^2.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-map-gl": "^7.0.21",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.0-beta.1",
    "react-swipeable": "^7.0.0",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "react-use-keypress": "^1.3.1",
    "react-whatsapp": "^0.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.58.3",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^4.7.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "webpack": "^5.78.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to change my node js version to higher and lower versions that does not work, I deleted the node modules and did npm install again, but it was still throw the error

Answer (score 0):

Check your TypeScript types: Make sure that you're using the correct TypeScript types in your code. Check that your TypeScript types are compatible with each other, the will find errors easily

your propertySlice.js, is js not .ts try to use ts in all your app.

Check your Redux store configuration: Make sure that you're configuring your Redux store correctly. Check that you're providing the correct reducers to the store

Check your Apollo Client configuration: Make sure that you're configuring your Apollo Client correctly. Check that you're providing the correct uri to the client, and that you're passing the client to the ApolloProvider correctly

That's all I could think of. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using const yourfunciton = () => {} instead of export default yourfunction() {} in all of your client side code. I am not entirely sure why this is the case but you can checkout this github issue here : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48070